# Run script on file change

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, windows, lua

I am stuck trying to solve a problem and could use some direction on how to solve.

I have a program running on a windows machine. While running the program writes data to a file in JSON format. When the program closes it stops writing to the data file, cleans up the file and then closes it.

I need to trigger a script when that data file is closed or changed.

I have tried accomplishing this with a lua script that is triggered by the running program as it shutsdown, but have been unable to access the file because it is still open when my script executes.

For this reason I am trying to figure out how to monitor the file for changes. Once the file has been changed/closed all I need to do is copy the file to another location.

I don't know what programming language would be needed to accomplish this, but guess python could do it. I don't have experience with python but am willing to learn if needed to accomplish this task. I do have some knowledge of nodejs, javascript and Lua.

Comment: question is unclear. What language do you use in your program? Maybe you should run script/program which runs your original program and when it finished then it runs code which copy file. And this should be possible in any language which can run other program - even `PHP` - using command sililar to `exec()`.

Comment: maybe you should save file directly in expected place instead of using `copy`.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is clear. I asked what language can be used to monitor a file for changes. The program in question is a commercial windows application and something I can modify. The file that is output is written to by the program whenever the program is running which is always with the exception of sceduled restarts. It during those restarts that I want to copy the now closed data file to another location where I will run other operations on it while the original file is re-opened by the program and starts being written to again.

Comment: for this question answer is - any language.

Answer (score 0):

The programming language is not the critical choice; use whatever is convenient for you.  The hard part is to make Windows report when the file is changed.

An operating system is a resource manager; trying to monitor a *target* resource for arbitrary changes can be very resource-intensive.  If you want to do it that way, you can schedule (cron) a one-line shell command that looks for any change since the last time it ran.  Check the modification time stamp.  If the file has changed recently, then fire off your script.

You cannot reasonably run a consistent monitor process.  That capability is too expensive to make an OS primitive, as is a "busy loop" check.

If your use case requires triggering your script on *every* change, even if consecutive changes are only milliseconds apart, then I know of no viable solution for your problem.  If you are satisfied with triggering only once every period (ten minutes?), then checking the modification time should be good enough for you.

Most of all, the "proper" way to deal with this situation is what you tried first: build your trigger into the design of the update program.  Without this coordination, your problem is equivalent to intrusion detection, which is *not* pretty in terms of system resources.

You can check the file's modification time directly from your `lua` script, using the [LuaFileSystem package](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html).  `attributes` returns a collection of file attributes, including the most recent modification time stamp.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree. My problem is that I have not been able to find a way to make my lua script wait for the other function that I do not have control of to finish writing to the file to execute which cause my script to fail. I am affraid this is beyond my ability but thought i would see if someone esle had an idea how to accomplish this as I have already asked about how to make my lua script/function wait with no luck.

Comment: Aha!  So you don't need a *permanent* trigger, just a one-time check while your script waits.  Can you not check the files status from lua?